# IOS: MKPinAnnotationView animated drop don't work

Tags: ios, uiview, mkmapview, mkpinannotationview

I have this code to delete and add a new pin in my map:

```
- (IBAction)setLocation:(id)sender{

    NSMutableArray *toRemove = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1];
    for (id annotation in map.annotations)
        if (annotation != map.userLocation)
            [toRemove addObject:annotation];
    [map removeAnnotations:toRemove];


    MKPointAnnotation *annotationPoint = [[[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init]autorelease];
    annotationPoint.coordinate = map.userLocation.coordinate;
    annotationPoint.title = @"Position";
    [map addAnnotation:annotationPoint];

    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotationPoint reuseIdentifier:@"Pin"] autorelease];
    pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
    pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
    //pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    pinView.animatesDrop = TRUE;


}
```

but I set my pin it don't do animation but I set animatesDrop = true, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this might help. I believe you might try using the [MKMapViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MKMapViewDelegate) (Apple Documentation, check the MapCallouts sample project) method:

```
   - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id < MKAnnotation >)annotation
{
    MKPinAnnotationView* customPinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];

// alter properties of the customPinView

    return customPinView; // if you return nil... then the MKPinAnnotation default will be dropped.
}
```

Make sure to add the `<MKMapViewDelegate>` protocol in the header

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're not adding pinView to the map.

Comment: no when I call this IBaction pinView appears...so what's you solution?